# How to compare a date in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running a SQL query which returns some orders each having a date. I want to check which orders were made on current date ?

I am able to do so by:

```
orders = Order.find_by_sql(query).reject {|o|
  today = Time.now
  end_of_today = Time.local(today.year, today.month, today.day, 23, 59, 59)
  start_of_today = Time.local(today.year, today.month, today.day, 00,00,00 )
  o.date > end_of_today
  o.date < start_of_today
}.sort_by {|o|
  o.delivery_date
}
```

'orders' contain all the orders which were made at any time Today.

Is there a simpler way of doing this in ruby ?

Comment: You should check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404175/query-where-date-date-today-with-rails-mysql-and-active-record

Answer (score 1):

To get the orders made on the current date, you can do the following:

```
orders = Order.where("date >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).order(:delivery_date)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use `DateTime.now.beginning_of_day`

```
Order.where('date >= ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day).order(:delivery_date)
```

Comment: `Time.current` or `Time.zone.now` are preferred, so they use the application's timezone, rather than the computer's timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are getting all the orders from the database (depends on what string is in the `query`) and then filtering the array, which is not the most efficient way if you have a large database. Much better way is doing this on SQL side.

Just use pure string conditions:

```
# Or set it to any other date in the past
target_date = Time.zone.now 

orders = Order.find_by_sql(query)
.where("date >= ?", target_date.beginning_of_day)
.where("date <= ?", target_date.end_of_day)
.order(:delivery_date)
```

More details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions

More info on Active Support DateTime methods: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-beginning_of_day

Comment: why you find `.where("date <= ?", Time.zone.now.end_of_day)`??? Today is not finished!

Comment: I've changed my code to show the concept of how one can select orders from the past as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this, it will cover all orders for today

```
orders = Order.where("created_at <= ? AND created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.end_of_day, Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).order(:delivery_date)
```