# What format should I write the date in to to make Date.today == ????? true?

Tags: date, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So here is what I have so far in IRB:

```
> Date.today
  => Tue, 14 Oct 2014 
> Date.today == (10-14-2014)
  => false 
> Date.today == (14-10-2014)
  => false 
> Date.today == (2014-14-10)
  => false 
> Date.today == (2014-10-14)
  => false 
> Date.today == (10/14/2014)
  => false 
> Date.today == (14/10/2014)
  => false
```

What format to I have to write the date to make that statement true?  I'm asking because I have a model that has a date field and I have to search by a specific date.

Thanks.

Comment: ... You should make it a date, not a division or subtraction problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see your both the object are not date type so you can not match both, if you want to create a search for date you can use this

```
Date.parse(params[:selected_date])
```

For more reference see this [Rails ActiveRecord Find / Search by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211916/rails-activerecord-find-search-by-date), hope it will help you